# How to test a chef recipe with encrypted data bags

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen, inspec

So in my recipe I have the following:

```
secret = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("/root/.chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret")

# Decrypt the data bag
creds = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("passwords", "mysql-root", secret)
```

How can I override these lines with my test data? The recipe installs a MySQL database, hence, I would like to test for the existence of the DB.

Answer (score 1):

i have created separate data bags for test with the desired secrets and load them, if its a test kitchen run

Comment: my first foray into test kitchen and chef...do you actually use the same values that you would in prod? for example, i have a root password set in the data bag for mysql install. this gets set in the recipe but during test kitchen my test fail if i dont have the right password. therefore, i need to reference the password from the encrypted data bag.

Comment: Why dont u set a different test password/acc for the test env ... i build local kitchen vm... so i have different secrets wrt prod

Comment: well, the recipe references a root password to use from an encrypted data bag. wouldnt test kitchen run and need said password? but i think what you're implying is i can make the recipe read from a different data bag all toigether?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to not use encrypted bags at all for testing, change your code to use the `data_bag_item()` helper instead of the underlying classes and it will work with both. Then just put some normal data bag fixtures in `test/integration/data_bags/` (or set `data_bags_path` in your config to load from elsewhere).

Comment: First time I'm seeing references to `data_bag_item()` ... use that in my normal recipe or in my test spec files?

Comment: Recipe, https://docs.chef.io/data_bags.html#with-recipes covers the DSL.